# Dovecot-core wont start. Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

Tags: linux, ubuntu, email, imap, dovecot

When I run `sudo service dovecot start` the error I get is:

> Job for dovecot.service failed because the control process exited with
>   error code. See "systemctl status dovecot.service" and "journalctl
>   -xe" for details.

So, when I run `systemctl status dovecot.service` it outputs:

[image]

Comment: And what is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by disabling ipv6.